# in CiviMail, when using "view in browser" link, how can forward to a friend be disabled?

Tags: email, tokens

When a person clicks on the *view in browser* link in an email, the email is generated on a webpage. This webpage also includes any tokens like Forward to a friend, which on this webpage does not work. How can the html for the web-page version of the email be edited to get rid of such token (or the unsubscribe token?)

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping those items in `<span class="hiddenElement"> </span>`. Civi's css will hide it on your website, but email clients will not.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for the suggestion, Coleman, but we can't get the "hiddenElement" class to affect the display. We are particularly keen to hide the 'Unsubscribe' link at the bottom of our emails when 'viewed in browser'.

Are there any plans to allow the 'View in Browser' page link within the mailing to be include a Contact ID (and a key token to prevent forgery?) so that 'Unsubscribe' can work as expected, even when the mailing is being 'viewed in browser'?